# @Secured Spring Security Annotation on JPA Entity not working

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have a JPA Entity class and am trying to secure the remove method by adding a secured annotation to that method. My JPA entities are not defined in my application context xml so I have used the following in my context.xml to try to enable Aspect J.

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" mode="aspectj"  />
```

I am using a maven plugin to do static compile time weaving and in my log I can see no issues

```
Generating code...

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) @ SubmissionTool ---
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO]
```

My JPA entity that I have defined the annotation on is a abstract class and it has child classes that use the remove method. The following annotations exists on my JPA class

```
@Entity
@Configurable
```

and the remove method is like

```
@Transactional
    @Secured(value = {"ROLE_ADMINS"})
    public void remove() {
        if (this.entityManager == null) this.entityManager = entityManager();
        if (this.entityManager.contains(this)) {
            this.entityManager.remove(this);
        } else {
            Submission attached = Submission.findSubmission(this.id);
            this.entityManager.remove(attached);
        }
    }
```

The Role ROLE_ADMINS should only allow those users with that role to delete a entity however all users are able to delete the entity. Any ideas?

Below is how my pom looks for weaving plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version> 
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                          <basedir>src/main/java/</basedir>
                          <includes>
                            <include>**/entity/*.java</include>                         
                          </includes>                        
                        </source>
                      </sources>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```